# how the filter function work when object passed into the JSON.Stringfy() has a toJSON() method?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm reading **Professional JavaScript for Web Developers**. there are some content about how the JSON.Stringfy() works in chapter 23. the follow content is a quote from the book:

When an object is passed into JSON.stringify(), the following steps are taken:

1. Call the toJSON() method if it’s available to retrieve the actual value. Use the default serialization otherwise.
2. If the second argument is provided, apply the filter. The value that is passed into a filter function will be the value returned from Step 1.
3. Each value from Step 2 is serialized appropriately.
4. If the third argument is provided, format appropriately.

I just can't get the point of second one. if the object passed into the function has a toJSON() method which returns a array and second argument which is a filter funcion is passed into the JSON.stringfy(), it seems that code lost the **filter** function, here are my code.

```js
let book = {
    title: "Professional JavaScript",
    authors: [
        "Nicholas C. Zakas",
        "Matt Frisbie"
    ],
    edition: 4,
    year: 2017,
    toJSON: function() {
        return [this.title,this.authors,this.edition,this.year];
    }
};
let jsonText = JSON.stringify(book,(key,value)=>{
    switch(key) {
        case "authors":
            return value.join(",")
        default:
            return value;
    }
    console.log(`key ===> ${key},value ===> ${value}`);
});

console.log(jsonText);
// ["Professional JavaScript",["Nicholas C. Zakas","Matt Frisbie"],4,2017]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*code lost the filter function*"?

Comment: If you expect to get output from the ``console.log(`key ===> ${key},value ===> ${value}`);``, that's not possible as your filter function always `return`s before executing that line - move it in front of the `switch` statement. And that has nothing to do with the (non)existence of the `toJSON` method, it doesn't work regardless whether `book` has one or not.

Comment: `console.log`, this line is for debuging. My meaning is that I can get expect output if I didn't override toJSON() method in `book`. but when I override the method and pass filter function into JSON.stringfy()'s second argument, what's the meaning about "The value that is passed into a filter function will be the value returned from Step 1.", I even lost key's value - the output of `${key}` is blank.